# How to make a sound in OSX using python 3

Tags: python, macos

So I am trying to play a simple beep after my code has finished because it takes a while to crunch a lot of data. I have tried other examples on the web, but nothing seems to work. I have tried:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('\a')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

which outputs the word bel in the IDE shell, but nothing else

I have also tried:

```
import os
print('\a')
```

which outputs the same exact thing.

And I have tried

```
import os
os.system('play --no-show-progress --null --channels 1 synth %s sine %f' % (   4, 4))
```

which simply outputs:

```
sh: play: command not found
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Also here is a jpg containing the word bell. It looks funny...
[image: Image of 'Bel']

I also made sure my volume was up

UPDATE: It might just be my IDE. I tried launching python directly from terminal and using write('\a') and it worked. It just won't work in wing 101

Comment: `sys.stdout.write('\a')` works for me, at least on macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Comment: on Mac 14.2 `sys.stdout.write('\a')` works in terminal - not vscode - with a "tok" and outputs 1. `print('\a')` also works and no output.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Acutually,`sys.stdout.write('\a')` works for me,but not in IDE,try to run this code in **Terminal**.You will hear the system sound.

Also you can try this two command:

- `say`
- `afplay`

---

e.g.

```
import os
os.system('say "Beer time."')

import os
os.system('afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Sosumi.aiff')
```

Run `man say` to see more details.

> say Hello, World.
>   say -v Alex -o hi -f hello_world.txt.
>   say --interactive=/green spending each day the color of the leaves.
>   say -o hi.aac 'Hello, [[slnc 200]] World'.
>   say -o hi.m4a --data-format=alac Hello, World.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this works. By chance though do you know how to make a generic bell or whistle and not human speech?

Comment: Asweome. How can we make the text a variable? Say txt = "Beer time."  and os.system('say txt')

Comment: @chikitin `os.system(f"say {txt}")`

Answer (score 8):

In Mac, you can:

```py
# List of voices: say -v ?
import os
def say(msg = "Finish", voice = "Victoria"):
    os.system(f'say -v {voice} {msg}')
```

Usage:

```py
# Run your program/experiment...
say() # say finish at the end

# Or say something more exciting
say("Great! Finally finished, please check the result!") 

# Or switch to another voice
say("Great!", "Alex")
```

You can also find other human language examples in my GitHub repo:https://github.com/hkpeterpeter/finish_alert

Answer (score 0):

Install `pygame`, https://www.pygame.org/.

Then go and have a look at the answers here: [Simple Pygame Audio at a Frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816294/simple-pygame-audio-at-a-frequency)